# How to create Network Dataset for Network Assistant using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, network-analyst

Is it possible to create a network dataset with ArcPy to be used with the network assistant?

In the documentation I found the [**Build Network**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/0048/00480000000v000000.htm) and [**Dissolve Network**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/0048/00480000000w000000.htm) functions, but it looks like both require an already existing network dataset as input parameter.

In this [**thread**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/11290-creating-network-dataset-using-model-builder-or-Python-script) people say it is not possible with Python but with [**.NET**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Network_datasets/000100000mrr000000/). In this [**thread**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008Dxl&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=ArcGIS%2bServer&sort=comments), somebody says it is possible to create geometric networks with arcpy in [**10.1**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015t000000). Is it possible to use a geometric network with the network assistant?

In the documentation  it says: Only point and line feature classes are supported as input. The feature classes cannot participate in another geometric network or other advanced geodatabase dataset such as a topology, network dataset, terrain, or fabric.

Comment: Which ArcGIS version and license level are you using?  Your link says 10.1 and Standard or Advanced is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create a network dataset with arcpy at this time. Your option is to use ArcObjects. There is a [Street Data Processing](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=755f96fcde454ece8f790fecb3e031c7) toolbox that is built on .NET by Esri (the source code is provided), which you might modify to meet your business workflows. A GP tool which is part of the toolbox creates a network dataset with certain user-defined parameters, so this should work fine for you too.

Geometric networks and network datasets are not the same thing and you cannot create a network dataset from a geometric network in ArcGIS. The only option is to use ArcObjects at this time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I go for now with the custom approach, but as soon as I can benefit more from the network analyst features I will try it. It's a pitty that it is not possible to create network datasets directly from Python.

Answer (score 2):

As I currently only need all shortest paths between two set of points, I ended up by calculating the shortest paths on my own with the Python binding of the [igraph library](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/). What I have is an input data set with points and a dataset with the street network as set of polylines with start node, end node and length. What I do is first find for each data point the nearest point on the road network. Then I create the graph from the road network. For each data point, I add two new edges to the graph. This is actually the biggest part of the code. Maybe there are more elegant and shorter versions. I know for each data point the id of the polyline nearest to it. For each such polyline I iterate over the segments and check if the nearest point of the data point is on the segment or the points between.

```
'''
Created on 13.05.2013

Create graph from road network dataset and find shortest path  

'''

import arcpy
import igraph
from collections import defaultdict


poi_layer = 1  # Layer with points of interests.
street_layer = 2  # Layer with streets as polylines. Start and end vertex ids in fields

# Find for every poi closest point on road entwork
arcpy.analysis.Near(poi_layer, street_layer, location="LOCATION")

# Set of ids of all polylines containing a nearest point
intersect_points = defaultdict(set)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(poi_layer, ("SHAPE@", "NEAR_FID", "NEAR_DIST", "NEAR_X", "NEAR_Y", "OBJECTID")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        near_fid = row[1]
        near_dist = row[2]
        near_x = row[3]
        near_y = row[4]
        objectId = row[5]
        id = str(objectId)
        intersect_points[near_fid].add(
            (near_x,
             near_y,
             near_dist,
             id,
             objectId))
del row
del cursor

# Create Road Network
vertices = set()
edges, weights = [], []

fields = ["FNODE_", "TNODE_", "SHAPE@", "LENGTH", "OBJECTID_1"]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(street_layer, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        s = str(int(row[0]))  # Start node id
        t = str(int(row[1]))  # End node id
        line = row[2]  # Polyline object of road
        length = row[3]  # Road length
        lineid = row[4]  # Road id

        vertices.add(s)
        vertices.add(t)

        # Check if road near to some data points
        if lineid in intersect_points:

            # For each intersection point
            for ip in intersect_points[lineid]:

                ip_near_distance = ip[2]
                ip_source_id = ip[3]

                intersect_point = arcpy.Point(ip[0], ip[1])
                last_point = None
                found = False
                length_from = 0.0
                length_to = 0.0

                # Check for each line segment if it intersects
                for part in line:

                    for current_point in part:

                        current_point_pg = arcpy.PointGeometry(current_point)

                        # Check if intersection point is on line point
                        if current_point_pg.contains(intersect_point):
                            found = True
                            length_from += ip_near_distance
                            length_to = ip_near_distance

                        if last_point is not None:

                            # Create line segment
                            array = arcpy.Array()
                            array.add(last_point)
                            array.add(current_point)
                            last_point_pg = arcpy.PointGeometry(last_point)
                            segment = arcpy.Polyline(array)

                            # Check if intersection point is on line segment
                            if not found and segment.contains(intersect_point):
                                found = True
                                length_from += ip_near_distance + \
                                    last_point_pg.distanceTo(intersect_point)
                                length_to = ip_near_distance + \
                                    current_point_pg.distanceTo(
                                        intersect_point)
                                last_point = current_point
                                continue

                            if found:
                                length_to += segment.length
                            else:
                                length_from += segment.length

                        last_point = current_point
                if not found:
                    print "Int point not found!"

                # If interection point found road, add new node to
                # network
                else:

                    vertices.add(ip_source_id)

                    # Add edge from start node to data point
                    edges.append((s, ip_source_id))
                    weights.append(length_from)

                    # Add edge from data point to end node
                    edges.append((ip_source_id, t))
                    weights.append(length_to)

        # Add road to network
        e = (s, t)
        w = length

        edges.append(e)
        weights.append(w)

del row
del cursor

# Create road network graph
g = igraph.Graph()
for v in vertices:
    g.add_vertex(v)
for e in edges:
    g.add_edge(e[0], e[1])
g.es["weight"] = weights

# Find location points
sources =  # List of vertices ids
targets =  # List of vertices ids

# Find shortest paths
shortest_paths = g.shortest_paths(
    sources,
    targets,
    weights="weight",
    mode="ALL")
```